# JGraphT - how to modify graph with Topological sort (not asking how to iterate topologically!)

Tags: jgrapht, topological-sort

Does JGraphT has ability to run a Topological Sort on a graph that will purge forward edges (or at least label them as such) and the resulting graph will have accessible root list of nodes (top level nodes of all trees in the graph)

Comment: On SO we share code along with known input and desired output.

Comment: Is that true of ALL questions on SO? This happens to be a concept question, if you don't understand the question - don't answer it.